# Launching XCUITests programmatically?

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcuitest

Does anyone know if this is possible?

By default Xcode launches UI automation tests for which it finds methods starting with 'test' in classes. As I'm writing a test framework around XCUITest this way of launching tests is very inflexible however.

I'd prefer to be able to provide facilities in my framework to register test classes and launch tests programmatically rather than Xcode doing this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but I would advise you to take a look at the [XCTestSuite class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestsuite). You should be able to register test classes programmatically.